# How does a derived class in multilevel inheritance override a middle level class method without being defined in the base class

Tags: c++

I am creating the Ants Versus Bees game and I have a multilevel inheritance hierarchy that looks basically like this:

```
class Insect
{
public:
    Insect();
    virtual ~Insect();

    virtual unsigned int getHealth() const = 0;
    virtual unsigned int GetArmor() const = 0;
}

class Ant :
    public Insect
{
public:
    Ant();
    ~Ant();

    virtual unsigned int GetArmor() const = 0;
    virtual unsigned int GetFoodCost() const = 0;
}


class HarvesterAnt :
    public Ant
{
public:
    HarvesterAnt(unsigned int armor, unsigned int food_cost);
   ~HarvesterAnt();

   virtual unsigned int GetArmor() const;
   virtual unsigned int GetFoodCost() const override;

};
```

What I want to do is override the GetFoodCost() method from the Ant class, which I would like to be abstract, because I don't think the Insect class should have that method. The reason is because the Bee class inherits from Insect and doesn't need the food cost method.
Bee class for reference:

```
class Bee :
    public Insect
{
public:
    Bee();
    ~Bee();
    virtual unsigned int getHealth() const;
    virtual unsigned int GetArmor() const;
};
```

When I instantiate for example a Harvester Ant class like `ant = std::make_unique<HarvesterAnt>(5, 10);` I can't class the GetFoodCost() method, I can only call the GetArmor and GetHealth methods.
ant variable definition for reference: `std::unique_ptr<Insect> ant;`
Can the Ant class actually be an abstract class?
I have tried to make the method pure virtual, virtual, non-virtual, and now I'm wondering whether this can be or I'm just missing something. I've found examples of Multi-level inheritance but they are super basic and don't involve pure virtual methods and abstract base classes. I may be asking this in a really dumb way so let me know if I can provide any clarification.
I am compiling with C++17 on Ubuntu 22.04 and g++ (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0

I have tried to override the method in the lowest level, HarvesterAnt class, but can't seem to access the method unless it is a pure virtual method in the highest level, Insect class.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot invoke `GetFoodCost` on an `Insect` because `Insect` doesn't have a `GetFoodCost` member function.

The `Ant` class can be abstract, that's not the problem.

If you declare `ant` to be `std::unique_ptr<Ant>` then you can call `GetFoodCost` through it

```
std::unique_ptr<Ant> ant = std::make_unique<HarvesterAnt>(5, 10);
ant->GetFoodCost();
```

[live link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/G2hmKDPRihEPHoai) with working code for anyone else interested in running/answering

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I may just skip the multi-level inheritance and just have Bee be it's own class while the stuff like HarvesterAnt and all the other Ant's can Inherit directly from Ant. Although I suppose Bee can implement GetFoodCost and just return 0

Comment: @kjg That sounds like a better design to me